# JavaScript nested loop issue

Tags: javascript

I have a pesky little bug that I can't currently find so any help is greatly appreciated.  It seems like the idx increment is out of sequence.  The problem is that the data is off by one the inserted items.  I am getting two month 5 rows when the data does not support it.

The second month 5 should be month 6. In the chartData array it ends with month 5 and in the dataSet2 array it starts in month six. Something in my code is hosing it.

Correct item
    {
       MonthNum: 5,
       Month: '5-2015',
       ARBs: 18
    }

Incorrect Item
    {
       MonthNum: 5,
       Month: '5-2015',
       ARBs: 3
    }

should be 
    {
       MonthNum: 6,
       Month: '6-2015',
       ARBs: 3
    }

The code snip

```
    if(dataSet2.data.length >0) {
    var idx= 0;
    var moreToProcess = true;
    var totalForMonth = 0;
    var firstMonth = dataSet2.data[0].theDate.getMonth() + '-' + dataSet2.data[0].theDate.getFullYear();
    while(moreToProcess) {
        do {
            totalForMonth++;
            document.write(idx + ' - ' + dataSet2.data[idx].theDate.getMonth() + '-' + dataSet2.data[idx].theDate.getFullYear() + "<br />");

            idx++;
            if(idx>=dataSet2.data.length) {
                break;  
            };
        } while (firstMonth == dataSet2.data[idx].theDate.getMonth() + '-' + dataSet2.data[idx].theDate.getFullYear());
        if(idx > dataSet2.data.length){
            moreToProcess = false;
        } else {
            var item = new Object();
            item.MonthNum = dataSet2.data[idx-1].theDate.getMonth();
            item.Month = firstMonth;
            item.ARBs = totalForMonth;

            chartData.data.push(item);

            //reset variables
            totalForMonth = 0;
            if(idx >= dataSet2.data.length) {
                moreToProcess = false;
            } else {
                firstMonth = dataSet2.data[idx].theDate.getMonth() + '-' + dataSet2.data[idx].theDate.getFullYear();
            };
        };
    };
    alert("Done");
};
```

I have created a "working" [example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXGbwv?editors=101)
Updated: [Example](http://codepen.io/jd80104/pen/bdwyrb?editors=101)

Comment: Where's the recursion?

Comment: No, the second month 5 should be month 6.  In the chartData array it ends with month 5 and in the dataSet2 array it starts in month six.  Something in my code is hosing it.

Comment: Updated the codepen to better reflect the issue: [link](http://codepen.io/jd80104/pen/bdwyrb?editors=101)

Comment: Seems like getMonth returns a zero indexed value so that is why it was off by 1.  DOH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like getMonth returns a zero indexed value so that is why it was off by 1. DOH!

The date 6/13/2015 was returning 5 as the month where Jan = 0, Feb - 1 etc.  That means June would return 5 which is technically correct as far as javaScript goes but not for my purposes.  Simple answer was to just add 1 to the getMonth() so I got the value I was expecting.